# CSS decimal list style type, the hanging number doesnt have the same baseline as my header text

Tags: html, css, html-lists

CSS decimal list style type, the hanging number doesnt have the same baseline as my header text

http://mikejmitchell.com/list-style-type-decimal.png

how can i line these up

Comment: check if your li element has bottom padding

Comment: What is your existing CSS for your `ol` and `li` elements?

Comment: You will need to supply a pared-down test case of your HTML markup and CSS being applied. As shown [in this test](http://jsfiddle.net/GAW46/), changing font-size alone does not cause the baseline to misalign. My guess is the same as @thedev: you have padding on your element.

Comment: I could do with a look at an actual rendering too, if that's (somehow) easier than posting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some code would be nice. The only way I could recreate the error was by giving the blue text bigger line-height. So you might want to try tweaking the line-height (and maybe adding some top- and bottom-margins re-add the vertical spacing.

Comment: Thanks, line-height was the one.  Just a note that margins and padding affect both the list numbers and the list content equally(when applied to either the `li` or the `h` element)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 li { vertical-align:bottom;}
```